# I am using react-dropzone in react js project, can't display preview image in chrome while working fine in firefox

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using react-dropzone in reactjs project, while uploading images the preview  shows a broken link with a error  "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". it is working fine in firefox.
in there own site it is not working in chrome you can check here https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-previews. please guide what should I do in this.

> "I think this error is because URL.createObjectURL

```
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

const thumbsContainer = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  marginTop: 16
};

const thumb = {
  display: 'inline-flex',
  borderRadius: 2,
  border: '1px solid #eaeaea',
  marginBottom: 8,
  marginRight: 8,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  padding: 4,
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
};

const thumbInner = {
  display: 'flex',
  minWidth: 0,
  overflow: 'hidden'
};

const img = {
  display: 'block',
  width: 'auto',
  height: '100%'
};


function Previews(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
    accept: 'image/*',
    onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
      setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => Object.assign(file, {
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      })));
    }
  });
  
  const thumbs = files.map(file => (
    <div style={thumb} key={file.name}>
      <div style={thumbInner}>
        <img
          src={file.preview}
          style={img}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks
    files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
  }, [files]);

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
      <aside style={thumbsContainer}>
        {thumbs}
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}

<Previews />
```

Answer (score 3):

add return before files like this `return () => files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));` inside useEffect

Answer (score 1):

Currently the useEffect is revoking all blob URLs when files state update but we want the blob URLs to be available until component unmount.

Just change the useEffect implementation to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks
  return () => files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
}, [files]);
```

This will revoke the blob URLs on unmount and will allow you to see the previews when the component is mounted.